# How to know where comes a stack corruption from in the destructor?

Tags: c++, memory, gcc, c++11, memory-corruption

From some time now, I've been facing a problem and I didn't found a solution :(

I've a class like that:

```
template<typename Node, unsigned int Threads, unsigned int Size = 2, unsigned int Prefill = 50>
class HazardManager {
    public:
        HazardManager();

        HazardManager(const HazardManager& rhs) = delete;

        /* Some methods */

    private:
        Node* Pointers[Threads][Size];

        std::list<Node*> LocalQueues[Threads];
        std::list<Node*> FreeQueues[Threads];

        /* Some private methods */
};
```

This class is used inside another class:

```
template<typename T, int Threads>
class AVLTree {
    public:
        AVLTree();
        ~AVLTree();

    private:
        Node* rootHolder;

        HazardManager<Node, Threads, 3> hazard;

        unsigned int Curren[Threads];
};
```

And the AVLTree class is allocated on the stack. When the AVLTree gets destroyed, I got a segmentation fault in the std::list destructor. Here is the output of valgrind:

```
==9336== Invalid read of size 8
==9336==    at 0x419F69: std::_List_base<avltree::Node*, std::allocator<avltree::Node*> >::_M_clear() (list.tcc:74)
==9336==    by 0x419645: std::_List_base<avltree::Node*, std::allocator<avltree::Node*> >::~_List_base() (stl_list.h:401)
==9336==    by 0x418DF9: std::list<avltree::Node*, std::allocator<avltree::Node*> >::~list() (stl_list.h:458)
==9336==    by 0x418E66: HazardManager<avltree::Node, 1u, 3u, 1u>::~HazardManager() (in /home/wichtounet/dev/btrees/bin/btrees)
==9336==    by 0x418F19: avltree::AVLTree<int, 1>::~AVLTree() (AVLTree.hpp:154)
==9336==    by 0x418D9A: void testST<avltree::AVLTree<int, 1> >(std::string const&) (test.cpp:110)
==9336==    by 0x41831D: test() (test.cpp:180)
==9336==    by 0x41CFF8: main (main.cpp:19)
==9336==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

In my opinion, it's a case of stack corruption, but I've no idea where that can comes from... There are no errors during the use of the class itself, only when it's get destructed.

Is there tool that can help find this error or tips that helps to find when this kind of corruption can come from ?

I'm using GCC 4.7 to compile my application with debug symbols and no optimization.

Thanks in advance for any help or idea

Comment: How do you use the AVLTree in your test code? I.e. what happens between construction and destruction?

Comment: What is this? `HazardManager(const HazardManager& rhs) = delete;` Should the `delete` be there?

Comment: @Component10: do you understand what this line means ?

Comment: @Matthieu M. Oh right its C++11 - should have guessed :)

Comment: It's good that you `delete` the copy constructor, since you have raw pointers in your class. But you neither implement nor `delete` the copy assignment operator. Is it possible that you are assigning between two instances of this class?

Comment: @Robᵩ It was not the case, but the advice is good. 
For the others, it is indeed C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `boost::array` / `std::array` and use `at`, you'll get an `out_of_range` exception.

Comment: Oh my gosh... It was exactly the problem. How did you find out ? Just an intuition ?

Comment: @BaptisteWicht: I'd rather say experience, note that `Attila` had the same diagnostic. Out of bounds access is just common when using unchecked access methods :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible you are overindexing `HazardManager::Pointers` that corrupts the list, which you only realize when its destructor is trying to access memory that is invalid (as the pointer got garbled).